# why do I need to deploy views and controllers separately to azure web app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, web-deployment

I have been struggling with azure deployment via VSTS.
We have a .net core mvc solution and the VSTS Built and release go well and I can see all dll and necessary files are deployed. However, I get 500 error. After investigation, I noticed that if I manually publish both views and controllers from Visual studio, the website works fine.

In the build steps we have:
Restore -> Build -> publish -> publish Artifacts.

Is there anything I missed during build process. why do I need to deploy views and controllers separately to azure web app?

Any thoughts?

Build step:
--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) -- which is release

Publish step:
--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

The release definition:
very simple just using Deploy AZure App Service using 4.* preview version with its default values pointing to azure subs and package folder "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip"

Comment: What does your build definition look like? What MSBuild parameters are you providing, if any? What does your release definition look like?

Comment: just updated the build definitions and release we use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed now for us by doing all steps below:

1) since we are using a local agent, we clear resource and output directories each time when we trigger a build - if you are using Microsoft default agents, according to Microsoft, each time you will be allocated to a new agent so no need to clean it.

2) From the Kudo, I noticed that when somebody did a manual deployment, there were some folders and files, including views and controllers. So I have deleted all files and did a fresh deployment and it didn't break since then.

Nothing else I have changed in our build or release steps.